# Lagrange multiplier problem - how to solve x, y and lambda?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

A typical Lagrange multiplier problem. Have I done right and how to continue?

$ L(x,y,\lambda) = x(1-y)+\lambda (x^2+y^2-1)  $

$\Rightarrow$

$ L_x = 1-y + 2\lambda x=0$

$ L_y = -x + 2\lambda y=0$

$ L_\lambda = x^2+y^2 - 1 =0$

How to solve $x$, $y$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: It is worth noting that there is no reason to solve for $\lambda$, except to know that you have an actual solution $(x,y,\lambda)$.  The value of $\lambda$ is just an artifact of the formalism, but it has no significance.  If you are looking for global extrema and you have a way to know that they exist, then it is okay to take steps to eliminate $\lambda$ from your equations, find candidate points, and just evaluate your function at those points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $y=0$ then $x=0$ which is illegal. So then get rid of $\lambda$ in the two equations 
$$
1+2\lambda x=y\\
x=2\lambda y\\
\implies \frac{x}{y}=2\lambda\implies y=1+\frac{x}{y}x\implies y^2=y+x^2
$$
now get $x^2=1-y^2$ involved to find 
$$
y^2=y+1-y^2\implies 2y^2-y-1=0\implies (2y+1)(y-1)=0
$$
and $y=1$ or $y=-\frac12$. If $y=-\frac12$ we have 
$$
x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
if $y=1$, we have $x=0$.

Comment: What makes y = 0 lead to x = 0?

Comment: And why is not y = 1 compatible?

Comment: So critical points on the unit circle would be: $(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} , \frac{-1}{2})$ and $(\frac{- \sqrt 3}{2} , \frac{-1}{2})$ ? Any more?

Comment: There is one more, $(0,1)$

Comment: And so I attempted a geometric interpretation so that all solutions could come in.

Answer (score 0):

We consider

$$( F- \lambda G)$$

$$ \dfrac{F}{G}=  \dfrac{F_x}{G_x}= \dfrac{F_y}{G_y}=\lambda $$

$$ \dfrac{1-y}{2x}= \dfrac{-x}{2y}= \lambda $$

simplifying we have to solve

$$  x^2-y^2+y=0,\quad  x^2+y^2-1=0,\,$$

subtracting

$$ 2 y^2-y-1=0 ,\rightarrow \,y= (1,-\frac12)  $$

so $(x,y)$ results in:

$$ (x,y)= (0,1), (\pm \sqrt3/2,-\frac12)$$

and Lagrange multipliers $\lambda$  from second equation calculate to $ \pm \sqrt{3}/2 $

It is to be noted there are *three critical points.*

Area is maximized as shown yellow, unit circle constraint boundary is geometrically depicted below hopefully for a comprehensive understanding,

[image]